# React: Is it possible to call a higher-order component within a container component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

In my codebase I have a higher-order component (HOC) I use to add all the input validation functionality to a given component.  It works great when used on a defined component like so...

```
let NameInput = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="name-input">Name</label>
                <input name="name-input" />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

let NameInput = addInputValidation(NameInput);

module.exports = NameInput;
```

But I now have a need to define a series of inputs based on an array from the server.  Something like this...

```
let TestApp = React.createClass({
    render() {
        // Pretend the names array came from the server and is actually an array of objects.
        let names = ['First name', 'Middle name', 'Last name'];

        // Map over our names array in hopes of ending up with an array of input elements
        let nameComponents = names.map((name, index) => {
            let componentToRender = (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <label htmlFor={name}>{name}</label>
                        <input name={name} />
                    </div>
            );

            // Here is where I'd like to be able to use an HOC to wrap my name inputs with validation functions and stuff
            componentToRender = addInputValidation(componentToRender);

            return componentToRender;
        })


        return (
            <div>
                <p>Enter some names:</p>
                {nameComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
})

let addInputValidation = function(Component) {
    let hoc = React.createClass({
        getInitialState() {
            return {
                isValid: false
            };
        },
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Component {...this.props} />
                    {this.state.isValid ? null : <p style={{color: "red"}}>Error!!!!</p>}
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    return hoc;
}

module.exports = TestApp;
```

React doesn't like it when you try to render the result of calling an HOC from within another component.

I assume it has something to do with the fact that my `componentToRender` isn't really a React component or something.

So my questions are...

Why can't I call a HOC from within another component?

Is there a way to call a HOC on each element of an array?

Here's a jsfiddle that might help: https://jsfiddle.net/zt50r0wu/

EDIT TO CLARIFY SOME THINGS:

The array that I'm mapping over is actually an array of objects that describe the details of the input.  Including the type of input (select, checkbox, text, etc).

Also my `addInputValidation` HOC actually takes more arguments than just the component.  It takes an array of store indexes that will be pulled from the Redux store to be used for validation.  These store indexes are derived from information in the array of objects describing the inputs.  Having access to this potentially dynamic array is the reason I want to be able to call my HOC within the React life-cycle.

So mapping over my array of inputs might look more like this...

```
let Select = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let Text = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let CheckboxGroup = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let TestApp = React.createClass({
    render() {
        // Pretend the inputs array came from the server
        let inputs = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
        // Map over our inputs array in hopes of ending up with an array of input objects
        let inputComponents = inputs.map((input, index) => {    
            let componentToRender = '';

            if (input.type === 'select') {
                componentToRender = <Select labelText={input.label} options={input.options} />;
            } else if (input.type === 'text') {
                componentToRender = <Text labelText={input.label} />;
            } else if (input.type === 'checkbox') {
                componentToRender = <CheckboxGroup labelText={input.label} options={input.options} />;
            }

            // Here is where I'd like to be able to use an HOC to wrap my name inputs with validation functions and stuff
            componentToRender = addInputValidation(componentToRender, input.validationIndexes);

            return componentToRender;
        })


        return (
            <div>
                <p>Enter some names:</p>
                {inputComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: `addInputValidation` expects to be passed a component, but you are passing it an *element* (`<div />`). That cannot work. *"Is there a way to call a HOC on each element of an array?"* Of course. A HOC is a function and it's very easy to call a function for each element of an array. Whether that works or not depends on what the elements are and what the function expects. If you have an array of *components* it will work fine.

Comment: @Kory can you show us your addInputValidation HOC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing I think you're tripping over is the distinction between a component vs. an element. I find it helpful to think of a component as a function and an element as the result of that function. So all you're really trying to do is conditionally choose one of three different functions, pass it some arguments, and the display the results. I believe you want something like this:

(this can be cleaned up, BTW, just tried to preserve your code structure as much as possible)

```
let Select = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let Text = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let CheckboxGroup = require('components/presentational-form/select');
let TestApp = React.createClass({
    render() {
        // Pretend the inputs array came from the server
        let inputs = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
        // Map over our inputs array in hopes of ending up with an array of input objects
        let inputComponents = inputs.map((input, index) => {    
            let ComponentToRender;
            let props;            

            if (input.type === 'select') {
                ComponentToRender = addInputValidation(Select);
                props = { labelText: input.label, options: input.options };
            } else if (input.type === 'text') {
                ComponentToRender = addInputValidation(Text);
                props = { labelText: input.label };
            } else if (input.type === 'checkbox') {
                ComponentToRender = addInputValidation(CheckboxGroup);
                props = { labelText: input.label, options: input.options };
            }

            let element = <ComponentToRender {...props} />;

            return element;
        })


        return (
            <div>
                <p>Enter some names:</p>
                {inputComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your edit: The problem is still that you are returning a component instead of an element from the `.map` callback. But that can be easily solved by changing

```
return componentToRender;
```

to

```
return React.createElement(componentToRender);
```

---

The problems in your code are:

- `addInputValidation` expects to be passed a *component* but you are passing it an *element* (`<div />`).
- JSX expects to be passed an (array of) element(s) but you are passing it an array of components.

It seems the simplest way to solve your problem would be create a generic `Input` component that accepts the name and value as prop:

```
let Input = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>{this.props.name}</label>
                <input name={this.props.name} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = addInputValidation(Input);
```

Which is used as

```
let nameComponents = names.map((name, index) => <Input key={index} name={name} />);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  It cleared some things up.

It makes sense that a function expecting to return a component based on a component it was given would break when given an element instead.

My root issue is still unresolved. No fault of your's. I think I oversimplified some things.  I'll add an edit to clarify some of that.

What would be ideal is to be able to define a React component inside another component.  I have a feeling that's either impossible or an anti-pattern.

Comment: Regarding your edit, all you need to do to return an element instead of a component is `return React.createElement(componentToRender);`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way of course. But HOC is quite a painful way to handle validation in general.

[There is a different approach to validation](https://medium.com/@gaperton/react-forms-with-value-links-part-2-validation-9d1ba78f8e49#.opv5nun4y), based on [ValueLink pattern](https://medium.com/@gaperton/managing-state-and-forms-with-react-part-1-12eacb647112#.87low9pvl).

Just compare the resulting code to higher order components approach.

Comment: I like this idea but probably won't implement it at the moment.  Your Medium articles break it down nicely.  Do you use Redux/Flux in your React apps?  If so do you find Redux and ValueLink's functionality overlap or conflict at all?

Comment: I don't use Redux/Flux at all. Simple cases (which can be quite complex pages, actually) can be perfectly handled solely with links as it's shown here and it looks much better. https://medium.com/@gaperton/state-and-forms-in-react-part-3-handling-the-complex-state-acf369244d37#.qq1ag83pm

For large SPAs we are using https://github.com/Volicon/NestedReact/, which is universal state management solution integrated with Links. There are some examples inside.

And I have to add that I'm an author of all that stuff.

Comment: Yes, and the popular state management solution which is far from Flux and somewhat close to NestedReact is mobx. Doesn't have two-way data binding and serialization capabilities, though. But is popular.